# Drop shadow issue

Tags: css

Following is my jsfiddle in which i am trying to drop shadow on table.
The problem is shadow is droping on bottom and right of the table but not on left and top side of the table kindly let me know how can i modify the css of my fiddle so shadow will be droped on all sides of the table. Thanks,

http://jsfiddle.net/7RQtq/

```
.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 4px #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=4, Direction=135, Color='#000000');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Reset the x, y co-ordinates:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
border-radius: 5px;
```

#### Explanation

The first option is `x` co-ordinate, the second is `y`. So, resetting both to `0px` will give you centered. And, increasing the spread, the third value, will give you like Photoshop. Also, giving some `border-radius` will show exactly how you want.

#### Screenshot

[image]

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7RQtq/4/

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about the legacy IE filters, but for other browsers you can use `box-shadow: 0 0 16px #000;`. The first two values indicate offset, and the third indicates blur of the shadow.

- Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7RQtq/3/
- Generator Tool: http://www.webtutorialplus.com/box-shadow.aspx
- Spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#box-shadow

> The ‘box-shadow’ property attaches one or more drop-shadows to the
>   box. The property is a comma-separated list of shadows, each specified
>   by 2-4 length values, an optional color, and an optional ‘inset’
>   keyword. Omitted lengths are 0; omitted colors are a UA-chosen color.
>
> Where  = inset? && [ {2,4} && ? ]
>
> The components of each  are interpreted as follows:
>
> 1. The first length is the horizontal offset of the shadow. A positive value draws a shadow that is offset to the right of the box, a
>      negative length to the left.
> 2. The second length is the vertical offset. A positive value offsets the shadow down, a negative one up.
> 3. The third length is a blur radius. Negative values are not allowed. If the blur value is zero, the shadow's edge is sharp. Otherwise, the
>      larger the value, the more the shadow's edge is blurred. See below.
> 4. The fourth length is a spread distance. Positive values cause the shadow shape to expand in all directions by the specified radius.
>      Negative values cause the shadow shape to contract. See below. Note
>      that for inner shadows, expanding the shadow (creating more shadow
>      area) means contracting the shadow's perimeter shape.
>
> The color is the color of the shadow. If the color is absent, the used
>   color is taken from the ‘color’ property.

As you might imagine, you can create complicated (and elaborate) effects with a combination of these values, such as:

- http://studentwebhosting.com/tutorials/amazing-css3-box-shadow-examples/
- http://viget.com/inspire/39-ridiculous-things-to-do-with-css3-box-shadows

Answer (score 1):

First two parameters are x (right) and y (bottom) traslation... set them to 0px for a centered shadow:

http://jsfiddle.net/7RQtq/1/

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px #000;
```